How to use to_char in oracle correctly?
I have this query:
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET ENDTIME = COALESCE(:ENDTIME, ENDTIME),
    ELAPSEDTIME = EXTRACT(DAY FROM ((CAST (:ENDTIME AS TIMESTAMP(6))) - STARTTIME)) || 'd ' ||
        TO_CHAR(((CAST (:ENDTIME AS TIMESTAMP(6))) - STARTTIME), 'hh24:mi:SS.FF')
WHERE MISSIONID = :MISSIONID

My idea is that ELPASEDTIME is saved as something like this:
0d 12:08:16.132
1d 00:01:04.765
80d 07:04:08.235
Number of days with the d and then the time passed.
STARTTIME is TIMESTAMP(6) type.
ENDTIME is TIMESTAMP(6) type.
ELAPSEDTIME is VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) type.
:ENDTIME is the variable Ignition (the program I use) syntax uses.
However I'm obtaining this:
0d +000000000 00:00:47.899000
Any idea how can I rmeove the +000000000 ?
I feel like to_char([...], 'hh24:mi:SS.FF') should work but for some reason it doesn't.
Thanks in advance!

Why do you want to store it as a string in that (or any) format? Store it in an interval (possibly virtual) column, then you can use or manipulate it as a proper data type if you need to. If you want to display the value then you can't apply a format model to an interval, but you can format it manually.

@AlexPoole we have to store it that way because our client wants it that way :/ I proposed the vitual column that gets generated from the values but they want it that way for some reason... Not truly understand and my boss don't want to deal with them so... more work for me sadly

If you use:
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         INTERVAL '0 12:34:56.789' DAY TO SECOND
       ) AS formatted_interval1,
       TO_CHAR(
         INTERVAL '0 12:34:56.789' DAY TO SECOND,
         'DD"d" HH24:MI:SS.FF'
       ) AS formatted_interval2
FROM   DUAL;

The output is:



FORMATTED_INTERVAL1
FORMATTED_INTERVAL2




+00 12:34:56.789000
+00 12:34:56.789000



Despite the TO_CHAR(datetime) documentation stating:

Purpose
TO_CHAR (datetime) converts a datetime or interval value of DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE, INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND, or INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH data type to a value of VARCHAR2 data type in the format specified by the date format fmt. If you omit fmt, then date is converted to a VARCHAR2 value as follows:

DATE values are converted to values in the default date format.
TIMESTAMP and TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE values are converted to values in the default timestamp format.
TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE values are converted to values in the default timestamp with time zone format.
Interval values are converted to the numeric representation of the interval literal.


The actual behaviour appears to be that TO_CHAR(interval, [fmt]) ignores the format model and always displays the numeric representation of the interval.

If you want to display the values as a formatted string then you need to generate the output yourself from the component parts:
UPDATE AGVS_MISSIONS
SET   ENDTIME     = :ENDTIME,
      ELAPSEDTIME = CASE WHEN :ENDTIME < STARTTIME THEN '-' END
                    || ABS(EXTRACT(DAY FROM :ENDTIME - STARTTIME)) || 'd '
                    || TO_CHAR(ABS(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM :ENDTIME - STARTTIME)), 'FM00') || ':'
                    || TO_CHAR(ABS(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM :ENDTIME - STARTTIME)), 'FM00') || ':'
                    || TO_CHAR(ABS(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM :ENDTIME - STARTTIME)), 'FM00.000000')
WHERE MISSIONID   = :MISSIONID
AND   :ENDTIME    IS NOT NULL


However, a better solution is to use a GENERATED column and then the elapsedtime column will never be out-of-sync with the starttime/endtime columns:
CREATE TABLE agvs_missions (
  missionid   NUMBER,
  starttime   TIMESTAMP(6),
  endtime     TIMESTAMP(6),
  elapsedtime VARCHAR2(20)
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
                CASE
                WHEN starttime IS NULL OR endtime IS NULL
                THEN NULL
                ELSE CAST(
                       CASE WHEN endtime < starttime THEN '-' END
                       || ABS(EXTRACT(DAY FROM endtime - starttime)) || 'd '
                       || TO_CHAR(ABS(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM endtime - starttime)), 'FM00') || ':'
                       || TO_CHAR(ABS(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM endtime - starttime)), 'FM00') || ':'
                       || TO_CHAR(ABS(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM endtime - starttime)), 'FM00.000000')
                       AS VARCHAR2(20)
                     )
                END
              )
);

and the UPDATE statement can be simplified to:
UPDATE AGVS_MISSIONS
SET   ENDTIME     = :ENDTIME
WHERE MISSIONID   = :MISSIONID
AND   :ENDTIME    IS NOT NULL

fiddle

What's the meaning of FM in the TO_CHAR([...], FM00)? I suppose the 00 specifies how many numbers are written.

@Danielps1818 The documentation for format models (and, in particular, FM) is here.

@WernfriedDomscheit Fixed

As mentioned by MT0, TO_CHAR() does not work with INTERVAL data. Because the output format of INTERVAL is always the same and does not depend on any NLS settings, you may also use regular expression:
REGEXP_REPLACE(:ENDTIME - STARTTIME, '\+?(\d+) ', '\1d ')

